# Passing closed standard file descriptors to child processes

Tags: tcl

```
#!/bin/sh
# Tcl ignores the next line -*- tcl -*- \
exec wish "$0" -- "$@"

exec -ignorestderr -- {*}$argv >@stdout 2>@stderr

exit
```

_

```
$ wish test.sh -- sh -c date 2>&1 | cat
Thu Feb 13 23:08:09     2014
```

If I don't pipe stdout or stderr, I get: `channel wasn't opened for writing`. But if it's closed, I want tcl to pass the closed file descriptor to the child process. I don't want tcl to capture the output of the command.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use redirection of `stderr` at the same time as `-ignorestderr`. That option works internally by using redirection (into a pipe that has a simple drain on it), so when you mix the two things, they fight over the configuration of the subprocess's real standard error channel. You don't want that.

In your specific case, since you want `stderr` to be connected through, just omit the `-ignorestderr` option.

```
exec -- {*}$argv >@stdout 2>@stderr
```

Note that this is *different* from working with a closed `stderr`! That causes all sorts of things to break; nearly every Unix process you ever come across assumes that it's open and that they can just write to it.

Comment: Redirecting to `/dev/null` is much better than closing…

Comment: They assume it's open and they don't check the result of `write()`, so when it's closed, they don't die

Comment: Thanks for the hint about `-ignorestderr`

Comment: `$ grep -l x /asdas /dev/urandom 2>&-`  
`/dev/urandom`
As you can see, `grep` continue when it fails to print `grep: /asdas: No such file or directory`

Comment: @basin Virtually the same effect can be achieved with `2>/dev/null`, and that has the advantage of not having a closed standard FD. It matters, because the first `open` uses the lowest unused FD by default, and that can make weird things happen when that happens to be a script file.

Answer (score -1):

I read your question many times, but still failed to understand what you tried to do. However, your script seems too complicated. If all you want to do is to capture the output of the `date` command:

```
set output [exec date]
puts $output; # Delete this line if you don't want any output.
```

Just calling `date` is enough, you don't have to do this:

```
sh -c date 2>&1 | cat
```

I know this might not be the answer you are looking for. If you still need help, please further explain in your question.

Comment: I see you don't know what closed fd is